# Unpacking Variadic Parameters via Lambdas

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I'm trying to avoid external functions or recursive calls so I decided to test the power of lambdas but I got stuck. How would I go about unpacking `Args...` using lambdas if possible?

I attempted to do `std::tie` to get the arguments into tuple then I tried to use `std::get<I>` where `I` is a non-const integer but it fails because get requires a `constexpr`.

I also tried initialization lists which I knew would fail but was worth a shot. I don't want to do it the Wikipedia way. I want to do it this way:

Any ideas or am I doomed?

```
template<typename... Args>
void fcout(const char* s, Args... args)
{
    std::function<void(Args... A)> Unpack = [&](Args... A) {
        //Unpack(A...);
    };

    while (*s)
    {
        if (*s == '%')
        {
            if (*(s + 1) == '%')
            {
                ++s;
            }
            else
            {
                Unpack(args...);
                fcout(s + 1, args...);
                return;
            }
        }
        std::cout << *s++;
    }
}
```

Comment: "*I'm trying to avoid external functions or recursive calls*" You're using variadic templates; external function calls and recursion *are going to happen*. Best to accept them now.

Comment: Ok but can I do it using recursive lambda's then? Or a forloop or some sort of C++ magic that probably doesn't exist..

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you expand a bit on what is your goal? Doing `A...` is "unpacking A"...

Comment: I want to access each value of A in my lambda. It doesn't unpack it. It just passes the whole thing so I can't do std::cout<<A...

Comment: Once you know what you want to do on each of them, the rest is not too hard. So all you want to do is do `std::cout << args...`? How about the lower part of your function (the `while()` stuff)? Is it an attempt to achieve that?

Comment: Yeah. It's the std::cout version of printf. It iterates a string aka the const char* parameter. It looks for the % sign. When it finds it, it looks attempts to print the corresponding argument instead.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: See my answer, I tried to provide a solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve, you can use this simple trick:

```
std::function<void(Args... A)> Unpack = [&](Args... A) {
    auto l = {((std::cout << A), 0)...};
};
```

Invoking the `Unpack` function object will cause all of the arguments to be inserted into `std::cout` (and, therefore, printed to the standard output).

Comment: :O this is close enough. I really wanted to get each argument but I'm happy with this. I'll place it into a stringstream instead. This'll have to do.